# Flutter voice transcribed using existing mp3 audio file

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text

Hello experts i need help i am creating app in flutter i need help is there any library available in flutter which transcribed audio from existing mp3 file  i know speech to text but real voice transcribed i want  if i have already recorded mp3 file i want transcribed it i also check google cloud speech to text its online and also very expensive i need offline and any free resource on native android i see many app  which already done this offline. But i don't how to achieve this task in flutter i also searched tesnflow lite i didn't see any library if you have any expertise in area please help me